# How to get element in class covered h3 by using BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, h2

I would like to get element "Orange" by using BeautifulSoup.
I only need an element which covered h2.
please help how to get it?

```
<h2 class="heading">
<a><span class="name">Orange</span></a>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<h2 class="heading">
<a><span class="name">Orange</span></a>
</h2>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("span", {'class': 'name'}):
    print(item.text)
```